# How to make sure async functions work seriesly in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

Given

```
const list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let results = [];
```

and a function

```
powerNumPlusOne = async(num) : Promise<any> => {
     return powerNum*powerNum + 1;
}
```

how to make sure this code work

```
list.forEach(async function(i){
   results.push( await this.powerNumPlusOne(i));
})
```

and the `results` should be `[2,5,10,17,26,37,50]` in order?

Comment: Your function does nothing asynchronous. Just make it synchronous, don't return a promise, and you won't have any problems. (Btw this is also the reason why your example already does output the expected result)

Comment: https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/index.html

`const _async = require('async');

let results = [];
let tasks = [];
list.forEach((i) => {
        tasks.push((callback) => {
          this.powerNumPlusOne(i).then(
            (res) => {
              results.push(res);
              callback(null, res);
            }
          );
        })
      })

_async.series(tasks, (err, res) => {
        console.log(res);
})`

Comment: No, if you want to work with promises, don't use the `async.js` library for callback-style.

Comment: yes. but it did work. I wrote codes in typescript. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could use Promise.all(). It accepts an number of actions and returns them in exactly the same order when all complete.

```
const list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let actions = list.map(powerNumPlusOne);
let results = await Promise.all(actions);
enter code here
```